# Rails: Authlogic failed login URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

On a vanilla Authlogic install set up a la [Ryan Bate's Railscast #160](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic), when a user goes to login and the session FAILS, the url changes from

```
/login
```

to

```
/user_session
```

(Of course, it shows the validation errors and all that jazz.)

I want to keep the URL always at `/login`, even on failure (and still display the login errors). How would I accomplish this?

PS - You can see this in his Railscast; scrub to 9:33 and watch the URL change on a failure.

Comment: actually this is a good question, I think the answer is the redirect that happens if the user_session is not saved correctly. Also I think it can be solved with routing.

Comment: If `user_session` is not saved correctly, a `render` is called, not a `redirect_to`. I experimented with `redirect_to`, but that seems to remove the validation errors. How might I solve this with routing? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the routing solution here: [Use custom route upon model validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083798/use-custom-route-upon-model-validation-failure)

Shame on me for not searching more thoroughly. Any other suggestions welcome, though, as I'm not crazy about the extra routes...