# How do I maintain the same controller & action in a page URL upon re-rendering an action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, authlogic

I am using AuthLogic to authenticate users in my rails app. That part is set up and workign properly.

I have the following route defined:

```
map.login '/account/login', :controller => :user_sessions, :action => :new
```

Calling rake routes returns what I expect:

```
login /account/login {:controller=>"user_sessions", :action=>"new"}
```

When someone submits a login, it calls UserSessionsController.create:

```
def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
        flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
        redirect_back_or_default account_url
    else
        render :action => :new
    end
end
```

If @user_session.save fails, the appropriate error messages appear on the screen. However, the browser URL also changes to "http://localhost:3000/user_session" instead of staying on "http://localhost:3000/account/login".

I assume the problem is what I am feeding to the render method. What should I be feeding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging, I found the solution in another StackOverflow question: [Use custom route upon model validation failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083798/use-custom-route-upon-model-validation-failure)

I simply modified my routes to add a new one for posing to '/account/login':

```
map.login '/account/login', :controller => :user_sessions, :action => :new, :conditions => {:method => :get}
map.login_post '/account/login', :controller => :user_sessions, :action => :create, :conditions => {:method => :post}
```

Then, I updated my view to utilize the new route:

`<% form_for @user_session, :url => login_post_path do |f| %>`

This works perfectly. A failed login gives the appropriate error messages and maintains the '/account/login' URL.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the intended behavior for this process. In a standard scaffolded RESTful controller, a validation error in the `create` and `update` actions will simply render the original template without redirecting. This results in what you are seeing – the `new` template will be displayed with the `create` action's URL in the URL bar. The reason for this is that in order to display information to the user about what errors occurred, the view must have access to the invalid model object, which is `@user_session` in your case.

You can use `redirect_to` instead of `render` if you want to force a redirect to the original URL, but this will cause you to lose information about the errors. You would need to manually persist the errors in the session, which would be messy. My advice is not to worry about the fact that the URL doesn't match that of the original as this is pretty standard in all Rails apps.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I find the forced inconsistency unsettling. Anyone getting errors on a page and wanting to report it will end up linking to a page whose link makes no sense when clicked. Using a redirect_to and persisting the errors is, as you say, messy as well.

Comment: There isn't really another choice. The data has to be persisted somehow. Either you don't do a redirect, or you store it somewhere and redirect.

Comment: I found an easy way to accomplish my goal without having to complicate my controllers and views in this manner. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding solution for Rails 4 (based on Shaun's answer here):

Add new route to routes file:

post '/carts/new' => 'carts#create', as: :create_post

Add url: create_post_path to form tag

Done.